# Getting the Japanese year name

Tags: java, localization

I have a program to get the Japanese characters year name：

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ja", "JP", "JP");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
Date date = calendar.getTime();

DateFormat format1
        = new SimpleDateFormat("GGGGy年", locale);
System.out.println("y: " + format1.format(date));

DateFormat format2
    = new SimpleDateFormat("GGGGyy年", locale);
System.out.println("yy: " + format2.format(date));

DateFormat format3
    = new SimpleDateFormat("GGGGyyy年", locale);
System.out.println("yyy: " + format3.format(date));

DateFormat format4
    = new SimpleDateFormat("GGGGyyyy年", locale);
System.out.println("yyyy: " + format4.format(date));
```

In the eclipse console to print is the case, which is what I want.

```
y: 平成1年
yy: 平成01年
yyy: 平成001年
yyyy: 平成元年
```

But when i made a jar,And cmd runs it,The output becomes this:

```
y: Heisei1年
yy: Heisei01年
yyy: Heisei001年
yyyy: Heisei1年
```

Do not know why this will become so,and i want get kanji.
please help me.
thanks.

Comment: works fine for me even in a jar

Comment: @Scary Wombat Then I feel more strange

Comment: ensure that the java class is up to date

Comment: quite strange, you ran the jar on the same machine?

Comment: What environment are you running the jar in vs eclipse? Java Versions, Operating Systems, Locale, etc

Comment: @Scary Wombat i'm sure the code is up to date

Comment: @choasia yes，Twice on one machine running

Comment: @Ryan The Leach java8,Win7,Locale is tokyo

Comment: @Y.Devil umm.. interested to the reason. Upvoted already.

Comment: Was hoping for a @JonSkeet to the rescue :P maybe he does sleep.

It's going to be one of those hairy questions I think, don't understand the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I run the following test cases:

```
    Locale WAREKI_LOCALE = new Locale("ja", "JP", "JP");
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("JST");
    Calendar jcal = Calendar.getInstance(tz, WAREKI_LOCALE);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("GGGG y-MM-dd zzz", WAREKI_LOCALE);
    sdf.setCalendar(jcal);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("GGGG y-MM-dd zzz", Locale.UK);
    System.out.println("got = " + sdf.format(1549556043201L) + " (" + sdf2.format(1549556043201L) + ")");

    System.out.println("got = " + sdf.format(-1357544756799L) + " (" + sdf2.format(-1357544756799L) + ")");
```

And got the following output with JDK 8 and JDK 11:

```
got = 平成 31-02-08 JST (AD 2019-02-07 CET)
got = 昭和 1-12-26 JST (AD 1926-12-25 CET)
```

See also:
https://github.com/twosigma/OpenJDK/blob/master/test/jdk/java/util/Calendar/SupplementalJapaneseEraTest.java